# Why my onclick event in JavaScript does not work?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm new at programming and I am trying different things and today I tried this:

HTML:

```html
<button id="button">Blue button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function() {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  element.style.color = "white";
  element.innerHTML = "Red Button";
}
```

And the console says: cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: The element that you try to access in your function is not defined anywhere, you need to either use `button.style.backgroundColor ...` instead of `element.style.backgroundColor` or you need to access the clicked element in the on click function. Passing in function a variable to capture the event `= function(e)` and then access the element `e.target.style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element probably hasn't been loaded when you tried selecting it. Add an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let button = document.getElementById("button");

  button.onclick = function() {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    button.style.color = "white";
    button.innerHTML = "Red Button";
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Blue button</button>
```